# Why do I get this error: Can't bind to 'latitude' since it isn't a known property of 'sebm-google-map' when adding the selector tags in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to get angular-google-maps / @agm/core working on my Angular 4 installation.

I have this **in the component html file:**

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

When I run it I get this **error message:**

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'latitude' since it isn't a known property of 'sebm-google-map'.
1. If 'sebm-google-map' is an Angular component and it has 'latitude' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'sebm-google-map' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<sebm-google-map [ERROR ->][latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></se"): ng:///AppModule/GoogleMapsComponent.html@0:17
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the error and I would like to share my solution with you.

To get the angular2-google-map now called @agm/core working it is important to update the **selector tags**. The author has not yet updated the docs (in this moment of the post).

**BEFORE last update:**

npm install angular2-google-maps --save

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

**NOW after latest update**

npm install @agm/core --save

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

**Example setup:**

*file: google-maps.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-maps',
  templateUrl: './google-maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-maps.component.css'],
})

export class GoogleMapsComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;

constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*file: google-maps.component.html*

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

*file: google-maps.component.css*

```
.sebm-google-map-container {
  height: 300px;
}
```

*file: app.module.ts*

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
@NgModule({imports: [AgmCoreModule.forRoot()}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian, the founder of the plugin has now updated the documentation and you can find the instructions [here](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/). My previous answer is still valid, but you probably find a more detailed answer at his site.